# The Uri string is too long - for the input parameter of my POST method

Tags: c#, post

I use fiddler to call my method, and for small strings it works perfectly.
However, my input parameter may be the content of a 250 MB file.

Here's how I call it:

```
POST

http://localhost:23234/api/myfiles

User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: localhost:23234
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 317210
```

And in the Request Body part, I have the content of a file which has 5.000 lines.

The method isn't getting hit. Instead, I get error 500, and the error messsage is: The Uri string is too long.

What can I do to make this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are hosting your API in IIS you should increase the maximum allowed request size (which by default is 4MB) by adding the following to your web.config:

```
<system.web>
    <!-- The value is in KB -->
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1048576" />
</system.web>
```

and if you are using Integrated pipeline mode:

```
<system.webServer>
    <security>
        <requestFiltering>                          
            <!-- The value is in bytes -->
            <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />
        </requestFiltering>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```

This will allow requests of 1GB to be sent.

Also you seem to have set the `Content-Type` to `application/json` so you should make sure that you are POSTing a valid JSON payload. Last but not least, ensure that you have selected POST in the Fiddler combobox with the verbs (the default is GET).

Comment: I added in my web.config <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2048576"/> and now the method gets called and the input parameter has a good value. But, in the first line of the method, I have: XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(theInputParameter);, and it crashes here, with the same error as before.

Comment: Did you set the `<requestLimits>` on the `<system.webServer>` tag? This is necessary if you are using integrated pipeline mode. Also you have shown a `XDocument` class but setting the Content-Type parameter to `application/json` which is inconsistent.